# Create Multidimensional array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have an array `district` which contains 36 districts, and I am fetching their president & secretary on the district id.

```
$districts=$this->dashboard->get_districts();
foreach($districts AS $district)
    {
        $contacts=$this->dashboard->get_contacts($district["ID"]);

        $result=array_merge($result,$contacts);
    }
```

and loading of view is:

```
$finalArray["result"]=$result;

$this->load->view("admin/view_contacts.php",$finalArray);
```

**Desired Array**
But I want an array of this shape, i.e. keys as district name, and sub arrays with contact details

```
$testarray=array(
            "Attock"=>array(
                "president"=>"gulzar",
                "secretary"=>"musa"
            ),
            "Bahawalnagar"=>array(
                "president"=>"muzamil",
                "secretary"=>"tania"
            )
        );
```

Comment: what you get by `$this->dashboard->get_contacts`? and where take district name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the correct key in your `$results` array. For that, you need something like:

```
foreach($districts AS $district)
{
  $result[$district['name']] = $this->dashboard->get_contacts($district["ID"]);
  //                 ^^^^ this is of course a guess and depends on your column name
}
```

Also, assuming that your `get_contacts()` method makes a database query, it might be more efficient to do a `JOIN` and get the combined necessary results in one database query. You can still loop over the results to build the required output array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$districts=$this->dashboard->get_districts();
$returnArray = array();
foreach($districts AS $district)
{
  $contacts=$this->dashboard->get_contacts($district["ID"]);
  $returnArray[$district['name']]['president'] = //Insert president value here.
  $returnArray[$district['name']]['secretary'] = //Insert secretary value here.
}
```